# Baking camera property drivers to keyframe

Tags: animation, camera, drivers, properties

I know its possible to bake the values of drivers to keyframes using `Object > Animation > Bake Action` but is there a way to bake a driver that is controlling a Camera's properties? I want to delete these drivers while keeping the same Camera animation.

Edit: Link to Blend

[image]

[link to comparison video](https://youtu.be/aFdU2iMNlMQ)

Answer (score 1):

**Quick script to bake camera data.**

Bake a `bpy.types.Camera` object's drivers to keyframes.

- Bakes all driven properties of `scene.camera.data` from `scene.frame_start` to s`cene.frame_end` in `frame_step` steps.
- Assumes there are no array type properties on camera
- Leaves drivers intact, will need to be removed. (Currently code used to remove camera drivers crashes my version of 2.8, and doesn't work on 2.79) Keyframes trump drivers.  Remove manually if happy with result.

Test script

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
cam_ob = scene.camera
cam = cam_ob.data
frame_step = 1
ad = cam.animation_data

f = scene.frame_start
if ad:
    while f <= scene.frame_end:
        scene.frame_set(f)
        for d in cam.animation_data.drivers:
            cam.keyframe_insert(d.data_path)
        f += frame_step
```

Comment: The script itself looks to have worked, and quite fast as well.
Im rendering the result and will mark as accepted answer if it works.

Comment: As previously said, the script itself looks to have worked for the project in Blender's viewport, but upon rendering (through the distributed render farm, Sheepit), the result is not correct (seems that the focal length is not adjusting as expected). I have updated my question with a link to a simplified version of the blend file and the rendered result clip to compare if you or anyone want to test locally.

Comment: As a rule to self, I don't download 90Mb files to answer BSE questions. Can you add a stripped down file with the driver set up (no vid) to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ? (paste link in question)

Comment: That is fair, I did not know that blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com existed. I've updated the link on the question

Comment: You are driving the `ortho_scale` on  a  perspective camera?

Comment: I haven't really questioned that. The camera movement is imported from a mmd motion via the [mmd_tools](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools) plugin which is creating the drivers automatically.

Comment: In case someone needs it: you can add `d.mute = True` to disable but not delete a driver.